# Find a matrix B such that $B^5 = A$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

I am being asked to find a matrix $B$ where $B^5 = A$

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

In the first part of the question I was asked to find the eigenvalues & eigenvectors for the matrix which I found successfully.
If someone could help me finish this then that would be great.

Comment: So what did you find? For the eigenvalues +vectors?

Comment: I edited your post to more properly $\LaTeX$ify it.  Cheers!

Comment: @Mason i got λ=4,λ=-2 for eigenvals. Corresponding to $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\  1 \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$A = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\  1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:** If you have found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, then you should easily be able to diagonalize this matrix as $A=PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ is diagonal. Then use the fact that $A^n=PD^n P^{-1}$, and the fact that the powers of a diagonal matrix are the matrices consisting of the powers of its entries.

Comment: Maybe, use $D$ instead of $B$ to avoid the confusion as the OP is asking to find $B$ such that $B^5 = A$. Also, this problem could be considered as a duplicate, I think.

Comment: @MathLover Oh, sorry. I will change it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Frpzzd any chance you could expand on the latter part of that suggestion. I know how to do matrix diagonalisation but what do you mean by "Then use the fact that An=PDnP−1, and the fact that the powers of a diagonal matrix are the matrices consisting of the powers of its entries." Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can also use projector decomposition. The left and right eigenvectors are equal, because of the symmetry. So the projector decomposition is
$$A=\lambda_1 \frac{v_1 \circ v_1}{v_1 \cdot v_1}+\lambda_2 \frac{v_2 \circ v_2}{v_2 \cdot v_2}$$
And
$$f(A)=f(\lambda_1) \frac{v_1 \circ v_1}{v_1 \cdot v_1}+f(\lambda_2) \frac{v_2 \circ v_2}{v_2 \cdot v_2}$$
Where $(a \circ b)_{ij}=a_i b_j$.